# MOSS 2007 workflow not copying particular column to another list

Tags: 2007, list, column, designer-workflow, list-item

MOSS 2007 workflow not copying particular column to another list

I Created a workflow to move the list items to another list. A column with lookup field type is not moving to another list. The column names and setup both are same in the two lists.

Comment: What is the actual question here? Is it "How do you move a lookup field from one list to another in a workflow?"?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by deleting the old columns and recreate the columns then my workflow is working fine.

Comment: If you solved the problem stated in your original question, you should mark this answer as accepted answer to help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you created the columns with feature their guid are different. I am afraid you have re-do the workflow where lookup column is involved.